# Excel Custom UI Addin Resets Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I created an add-in with a custom UI to add a tab and buttons for the macros.

A problem has cropped up on some users' computers where the Quick Access toolbar gets reset every time they open Excel. Mine reset the first time, but it's held on to changes I've made since.

I built my custom UI from scratch and did not use any third party software to do it.

There isn't any code within the add-in that affects the UI. The only code is a `Case` statement to run specific macros for specific buttons.

My custom UI xml file.

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="CRC" label="CRC Macros" insertAfterMso="TabHome">
                <group id="MPS" label="Schedule">
                    <button id="KTC_button" label="KTC MPS" image="ktc_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                    <button id="KTS_button" label="KTS MPS" image="kts_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                    <button id="KTV_button" label="KTV MPS" image="ktv_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                    <button id="split_button" label="Split Schedule" image="split_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                </group>
                <group id="CTB" label="Shortage Reports">
                    <button id="QD_button" label="Quick CTB" image="qd_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                    <button id="PL_button" label="Product Line or CSV" image="pl_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                </group>
                <group id="OTH" label="Other">
                    <button id="STG_button" label="Shipments-To-Go" image="stg_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                    <button id="peg_button" label="Format Pegged" image="peg_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                    <button id="MRP_button" label="MRP Summary" image="MRP_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                    <button id="MPS_Sum_button" label="MPS Summary" image="MPS_Sum_icon" size="large" onAction="ProcessRibbon" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ribbon XML markup looks good. It cannot be related to resetting the QAT in Office applications (Excel in your case) from the first sight.

First of all, you need to check out the list of Office add-ins. There can be any conflicts between extensions and your customizations.

Second, make sure there are no UI errors in Excel. By default, if an add-in (or any other kind of ribbon customizations) attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Third, it is not clear what your callbacks do. But ribbon is a static thing from its birth, so QAT can't be customized at runtime without loading a custom ribbon XML. So, only users or add-ins could do resets.